# How to get the size of kernel functions when compiling linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I know I can get the size of functions after compiling the kernel by using the command `readelf -s vmlinux|grep "some function"`.

However, the question is:
I have a function pointer array which is like:

```
void* function_pointer[]={(void*)foo1,(void*)foo2,...(void)*foon}
```

and I have a array which needs to store the size of functions above which is like: `int function_size[]={foo1_size,foo2_size...foon_size};`

how can I know each function's size so I can give the `function_size` array values. **Besides, the `CONFIG_KALLSYMS` is off, so I can not use symbol table.**

**Update**:The reason why I want to get the size of a function is :
In the caller stack of a function, we can get the return address of the function, and the return address of the function's caller and etc. But in the code, we don't know these return addresses, we can only use function pointers which are the start addresses of these functions instead. To compare which function a return address in the caller stack belong to, my idea is get each function's size and check if a return address is within the scope of a function.

Comment: Why do you need to know the size of a function?

Comment: Because I want to check if a address is within the scope of a function in my code.@duskwuff

Comment: Let's back up a step further. Why do you need to check this?

Comment: Please see the update@duskwuff

Comment: When compiling, function sizes are not stored in the final binary, only symbols that points to the different function entry points (and data). The most common and brutal way is to find the function entry point that is before the address in question. But as other people ask, why do you need this. The kernel already has API for creating text backtraces that can be utilized for this.

Comment: How can I find the function entry point that is before the return address? And is the kernel API you mention is dump_stack() or __builtin_return_address? The addresses they return are return addresses rather than start addresses.@StianSkjelstad